# How is Eq typeclass implemented for user defined types?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

For some user defined type such as the below how does the implementation of the Eq typeclass work? Its simple to write an implementation for things like Int or Float. But how is the catchall for all user types done since it would need to do things like pattern match against every possible value constructor? I'm not aware of any syntax to do this.

```
data Person = Person { firstName :: String
                     , lastName :: String
                     , age :: Int
                     } deriving (Eq)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It pattern matches against every possible value constructor, just like you said! For example, if you put your code in a file and run `ghc` with `-ddump-deriv`, here's what you get:

```
==================== Derived instances ====================
Derived instances:
  instance GHC.Classes.Eq Main.Person where
    GHC.Classes.==
      (Main.Person a1_alh a2_ali a3_alj)
      (Main.Person b1_alk b2_all b3_alm)
      = ((((a1_alh GHC.Classes.== b1_alk))
          GHC.Classes.&& ((a2_ali GHC.Classes.== b2_all)))
         GHC.Classes.&& ((a3_alj GHC.Classes.== b3_alm)))
    GHC.Classes./= a_aln b_alo
      = GHC.Classes.not ((GHC.Classes.==) a_aln b_alo)
```

Comment: You can do `:set -ddump-deriv` in ghci too

Comment: Oh so it generates the instance code specifically for the type Person. I was under the mistaken impression that some already written code is used. But how does it know how to generate the instance code? Is that baked into Haskell itself?

Comment: @user782220 Basically yes, it's baked in. That's the reason why you can only use `deriving` with certain type classes. There's no possible Haskell code that could work for any type, so you need type-specific logic (that's why equality is a type class function, not a polymorphic function). GHC contains logic to generate the "obvious" `Eq` instance (for any type that *has* such an instance).

Comment: If you're still curious, derived instances are specified in the Haskell'98 report: http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/derived.html

Comment: It's slightly misleading to say it's entirely baked in. With Template Haskell, normal people (yes you!) can write code that autogenerates stuff for arbitrary data types. lens makes heavy use of this.